# Входит ли географическая точка в полигон в форме правильного шестиугольника?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Нужна формула для проверки вхождения точки на карте в полигон в форме правильного шестиугольника. Центр имеет широту и долготу, каждая точка шестиугольника также имеет широту долготу. Длина сторон 200 метров.

Стороны шестиугольника для примера.

- Сторона a [ aX, aY ], [ bX, bY ] - это первая верхняя сторона шестиугольника, а дальше по часовой стрелке
- Сторона b [ bX, bY ], [ cX, cY ]
- Сторона c [ cX, cY ], [ dX, dY ]
- Сторона d [ dX, dY ], [ eX, eY ]
- Сторона e [ eX, eY ], [ jX, jY ]

Точки шестиугольника, отсчет первой точки первой стороны

- [ aX, aY ]
- [ bX, bY ]
- [ cX, cY ]
- [ dX, dY ]
- [ eX, eY ]
- [ jX, jY ]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Эх нет времени на развернутый ответ - теорема Коши об обходе замкнутого контура Вам в руки

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: если вам нужен именно результат посмотрите на метод isPointInPath(path, x, y) в  контексте canvas2d (в safari не поддерживается)

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов, isPointInPath  в Сафари не поддерживается? Откуда инфа?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath